# XSLT+JavaScript: using classes

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, class, function

I'm trying to use classes in XSL (the 'msxsl:script' tag). But I get the 'Syntax error' message when debugging the file. Here's a simple code that I'm using:

```
function Test1(str)
{
    this.str = str;
}

Test1.prototype.getStr = function()
{
    return this.str;
}

function test()
{
    var newTest1 = new Test1("some string");
    return (newTest1.getStr());
}
```

If I insert the code to a aspx file and call the test function, everything works fine, without any error messages.
Is it possible to use classes in XSL?

Comment: Can you please post the actual XSLT you are using. I think the syntax error has nothing to do with your use of classes.

Comment: Actually, everything OK with my XSL file. I can execute it without any problems (without the script). After inserting the script I got the syntax error on this line: 
Test1.prototype.getStr = function()
All code is located in msxsl:script. I also inserted CDATA.

Comment: Did you insert CDATA *and* escape `<`, `>` and `&` characters in the script? Only one is necessary - CDATA *or* escaping.

Comment: All the code is in CDATA. As you can see there's no <, > or other special symbols in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are some odd restrictions on what you can use at the top level of the script blocks, and that they won't allow the use of `this` in top-level functions. However, if you go one level deeper, some of these restrictions go away:

```
function MakeTest1()
{
   function inner(s)
   {
      this.str = s;
   }

   inner.prototype.getStr = function()
   {
      return this.str;
   }

   return inner;
}
var Test1 = MakeTest1();

function test()
{
    var newTest1 = new Test1("some string");
    return (newTest1.getStr());
}
```